# Pass array to Javascript onClick function while adding links into a string?

Tags: javascript

I know the question sounds strange, but it's really very simple. I have the following function which isn't working:

```
function start40Counter(counter40_set){console.log(counter40_set);
    var gid = counter40_set[0];
    var seat = counter40_set[1];
    var suits = counter40_set[2];
    var cont = "";
    $.each(suits, function (num, suit) {
        cont += "<a class='suitpick' onClick='pickSuit(counter40_set);'><img src='"+base+"images/someimg.png' title='Odaberi' /></a>";
    });
    $('#game40_picks').html(cont);
}
```

`counter40_set` is `[10, 3, ["H", "S"]]`. The part of the function that fails is the part this:

```
onClick='pickSuit(counter40_set);'
```

It says that `counter40_set is not defined`. I understand that. This wouldn't even work if `counter40_set` was a simple string instead of an array. If I try `onClick='pickSuit("+counter40_set+");'` I get a different error, saying `H is not defined`. I get this too, the array is rendered and JS doesn't know what H and S are.

I also tried passing the array elements (`counter40_set[0]` etc) individually but it still fails with the last element (`["H", "S"]`).

So, how do I pass this data to the `onClick` function in this case? There must be a more elegant way than concatenating the whole thing into a string and passing that to the function?

Btw, this is a simplified version. What I should really be passing in every iteration is `[suit, counter40_set]` so that each link chooses a different `suit`. I'm asking the simplified question because that will be enough to send me down the right path.

Comment: Well, how/where *is* "counter40_set" defined?

Comment: @Pointy as I said, `counter40_set` is `[10, 3, ["H", "S"]]` in this example. It's created in a back-end Node.js server.

Comment: So where is it defined *on the page*? It doesn't matter what it is on the server, what matters is how it's included with the code on the client. *edit* OH oh I see what you mean now.

Comment: @remyabel No, the problem lies where I said it lies, cardsuits is something different (a global var). I've removed it from the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Pointy The value is passed to the client through a socket. In the code above, `console.log` shows the value I named as the example. It's as simple as `socket.on('start40Counter', function(counter40_set) {
 start40Counter(counter40_set);
});`

Comment: Yes sorry, I was being dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot work,because the context is lost and thus "counter40_set" is not set.

To fix it simply use jquery for the onlick as well:

```
$('#game40_picks').empty(); // get rid of everything
$.each(suits, function (num, suit) {
    var line = $("<a class='suitpick'><img src='"+base+"images/"+cardsuits[suit].img+"' title='Odaberi "+cardsuits[suit].name+"' /></a>");
   line.click(function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault(); // prevent default click handler on "a"
      pickSuit(counter40_set);
   });
   $('#game40_picks').append(line);
});
```

this way the "counter40_set" is available for the click function.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the `onClick` HTML attribute.  Also, using DOM functions to build nodes saves the time it takes jQuery to parse strings, but basically the method below is to create the element and attach a click event listener and then append it to the specified element.

```
function start40Counter(event){console.log(event.data.counter40_set);
    var counter40_set = event.data.counter40_set;
    var gid = counter40_set[0];
    var seat = counter40_set[1];
    var suits = counter40_set[2];
    var cont = "";
    $.each(suits, function (num, suit) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.className = 'suitpick';
        $(link).on('click', {counter40_set: counter40_set}, start40Counter);

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src= base + "images/" + cardsuits[suit].img;
        img.title = 'Odaberi ' + cardsuits[suit].name;

        link.appendChild(img);
        $('#game40_picks').append(link);
    });
}
```

Not tested but it might work out of the box.